# Python equivalent of IDL retall?

Tags: python, debugging, user-interface

I have a GUI driven image analysis package in IDL that needs some serious rewriting. Python has been suggested to be as an alternative to IDL (with benefits of cost and some nice libraries among other things).  I've poked around now with PyQT4 and it looks like it should work nicely.  However, one of the best things about IDL (being interpreted) is that if the code hits a bug, you can correct it on the fly, type 'retall' and then continue with your work.  If you are hours into some analysis and have lots of datafiles open, etc., this is a HUGE improvement over having to exit, then change and restart the program.  Not only that but we can quickly try some things on the command line, then if it looks good, code up a routine, put it in the menu structure, and then 'retall' and we are back with the new functionality, all without ever having to restart the program.

My question is, is this possible with Python?  A little googling makes the answer seem like no but since it is an interpreted language I don't understand why not.  If the answer really is no I'd strongly urge someone to think about implementing this -- it is probably the feature that made me most happy about IDL over the past decade.

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: The below comment made me think though: what happens if I spawn off a process and that spawned process dies?  Does it bring the whole program to a halt, or will the main loop happily continue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done.

However, you may consider structuring your package to cache intermediate results on disk and to allow resume from thoses cached results. This has benefits outside the bug case you describe.

Fixing a bug "on the fly" seems potentially dangerous to me as it is so easy to overlook possible side-effects of the bug. It breaks the link between execution flow and code and make it extremely difficult to debug subsequent issues, etc ...

Comment: Thank you for the comment and suggestion.  For analysis tools this isn't such an issue.  If an analysis process dies (as long as it was really just analysis and not processing the data) when you kill that routine and go back out to the main loop there seem to very rarely be side effects (at least, the couple dozen of us who developed this in IDL regularly take advantage of that capability and haven't had issues).